# How to use bootstrap 4 margin and padding properties with pixels?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, frontend

I would like to use bootstrap 4 margin and padding properties with pixels instead of rems. For example, I would like the following div to have margin-left of 20 pixels:

```
<div class="container ml-20">Hi</div>
```

Is it even possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, not possible. But you can make up your own BS-like classes

Comment: Create custom classes. By default, there isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't have anything like this. However, you can create a custom css class to handle this for you:

```
.ml-20 {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Your options are limitless with how you want to set it up. You could create ml-10, ml-100 or anything you want.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like that in Bootstrap, but in CSS, just use the code

```
div {
  margin-left:20px;
}
```